# How to use namespace System; in MFC application with VC++

Tags: c++, sql, visual-c++, mfc, namespaces

help me,am new,
I want to use some features(i don't know the specific word to use) present in System namespace, but when i try to add it to my project by "using namespace System",i want this to use SQLCLIENT ,i saw below link giving answer but dont have a clue what he is talking about

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5429ca08-4e18-471e-a679-859094e9aa18/i-work-with-vc-2005-mfc-i-cant-use-namespace-system?forum=vclanguage

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you are learning, never use any 'using namespace' If the annoyance typing 'namespace::whatever' grows, you might consider using 'namespace::whatever' in a well defined scope. Finally, after more annoyance, you might consider 'using namespace' in a well defined scope. However, after a while you get used to  'namespace::whatever'.

Comment: Also: Be aware C++ and C++/cli are distinct (Your links are targeting C++/cli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace System is part of the .NET library, which requires you to use the C++/cli or C# language. MFC is a C++ library, programmed with C++. If you are new to all this I do not recommend you attempt to program in two languages. You can find some other way to use SQL in an MFC application. (Try looking up CDatabase and CRecordset).